# Running Python coverage collection around a process that forks

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, fork, coverage.py

I have a Python application I'm running within a Docker container. That application is normally started with the command `/usr/local/bin/foo_service`, which is a Python entry point (so it's just a Python file).

I want to collect code coverage for this application while running functional tests against it. I've found that `coverage run /usr/local/bin/foo_service` works nicely and, once the application exits, outputs a coverage file whose report appears accurate.

However, this is in the single-process mode. The application has another mode that uses the `multiprocessing` module to fork two or more child processes. I'm not sure if this is compatible with the the way I'm invoking coverage. I did `coverage run --parallel-mode /usr/local/bin/foo_service -f 4`, and it *did* output [one] coverage [file] without omitting any errors, but I don't *know* that this is correct. I half-expected it to output a coverage file per-process, but I don't *know* that it should do that. I couldn't find much coverage (pardon the pun) of this topic in the documentation.

Will this work? Or do I need to forego using the `coverage` binary and instead use the `coverage` Python API within my forking code?

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
$ coverage --version
Coverage.py, version 4.5.3 with C extension
```

Comment: Please forgive my idiocy. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297497/python-code-coverage-and-multiprocessing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Code Coverage and Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297497/python-code-coverage-and-multiprocessing)