# How to measure coverage when using multirpocessing via pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I run my unit tests via [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/). For coverage I use [`coverage.py`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

In one of my unit tests, I run a function via `multirpocessing` and the coverage does not reflect the functions running via `multirpocessing`, but the asserts work. That's the problem I am trying to solve.

The test looks like so:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def test_a_while_loop():
    # Start through multiprocessing in order to have a timeout.
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=foo
        name="Foo",
    )
    try:
        p.start()
        # my timeout
        time.sleep(10)
        p.terminate()
    finally:
        # Cleanup.
        p.join()

    # Asserts below
    ...
```

To run the tests and see the coverage I  use the following command in Ubuntu:

```
coverage run --concurrency=multiprocessing -m pytest my_project/
coverage combine
coverage report
```

In docs give guidance on what to do in order for coverage to account for multiprocessing correctly ([here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html)). So I have set up a `.coveragerc` like so:

```
[run]
concurrency = multiprocessing

[report]
show_missing = true
```

and also `sitecustomize.py` looks like so:

```
import coverage
coverage.process_startup()
```

Despite this, the above function running through `multiprocessing` is still not accounted for in coverage.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297497/python-code-coverage-and-multiprocessing) seems like a similar question, however it does not fix my problem again : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I "fixed" this issue by doing two this:

1. Switching the coverage package from [`coverage.py`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to [`pytest-cov`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
2. Adding this code above the `process` as described via their [docs](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess-support.html#if-you-use-multiprocessing-process).

Code:

```
try:
    from pytest_cov.embed import cleanup_on_sigterm
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    cleanup_on_sigterm()
```

Then I simply run `pytest --cov=my_proj my_proj/`